# $\{x: 2x^2\cos(1/x) \le 1\} \cup \{0\}$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove or disprove that $$ \{x: 2x^2\cos(1/x) \le 1\} \cup \{0\}\ 
\text{is complete}.  $$

Define $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & x\neq 0\\ 0, &  x=0  \end{cases}$$ Clearly, $f$ is continuous and $T=f^{-1}\big((-\infty,1]\big)$ which is closed and hence $T$ is complete.

Am I right?

Comment: Seems good to me!

Comment: Not sure I follow. Doesn't complete mean that every Cauchy sequence in a set converges to a limit that's also in the set? I don't see the relation to $f$ or anything you wrote.

Comment: @OriaGruber A subspace of a complete metric space is complete iff it is closed, and preimages of closed sets under continuous functions are closed.